# Firefox doesn't scroll with touch input on Windows

Tags: windows, firefox, graphics-tablet

I'm using a graphics tablet with support for Windows ink (basically Windows treats it as a touch screen) which works everywhere as intended, scrolling instead of selecting text and behaving like a touchscreen. On Firefox, however, it behaves as a mouse would, selecting text. I'm using Windows, and if I try this on a Chromium-based browser it successfully scrolls. I tried searching for information, but only found help for Linux.

Comment: What settings do you have enabled under Pen & Windows Ink? There is a checkbox that says "Let me use my pen as a mouse." If this is checked, you may try unchecking it and trying again. I doubt that will solve the issue but would be a good place to start.

Comment: @LayneBernardo just tried, when unchecked it doesn't start selecting until I release the pen and it keeps on selecting when not clicking, checking it again doesn't do anything. Maybe Firefox isn't supported on Windows? it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I'm not sure. I had the same issue as you when I tried to look into it, where all the answers were about Linux. It does sound like some conflict between Windows Ink behavior and Firefox's built-in behavior but I don't know how you'd go about fixing it. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will see this post.

Comment: What tablet? It should have a driver and a config tool, there should be an option to disable the mouse click.